# Fortran New Output File

Tags: fortran

I'm new to Fortran, and trying to repurpose a bit of code that is part of a larger program I've inherited. When the program is run, it prompts for output file names. I would prefer to specify these output file names directly in the code, so I can run the program in parallel/all at once (the run time of the program is about 15 hours, and needs to be run for 66 different files, so I would prefer to run them all at once as opposed to one after another because that would take quite a long time).

The bit of code I'm working with looks like this:

```
24  print *,'Enter output filename'
25  read(*,*) fout
26  print *,'Enter parameter estimate output filename'
27  read(*,*) foutb
28  print *,'Enter seed for random number generator'
29  read(*,*) idum
30  if(idum.gt.0) idum = -idum
```

Everything I've tried gives me:

```
At line 25 of file v1.f95:
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

I've checked that I have proper line endings. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: That error probably comes from elsewhere - from code that is trying to read more from a file than the file can give.  What have you actually tried?  Do you have a computer with 66 execution cores?  If not, trying to run 66 programs all at the same time might not give you the speed-up that you anticipate.

Comment: The reason I (think I) know error comes from that part of the code is because it says `At line 25 of file v1.f95` just before the error code, and this part of the code begins on line 24. I have a access to a computer cluster with enough nodes, so that's why I'd like to get this to work. I have tried removing the `print` lines, and tried various ways of redirecting the read files, like so: `read(*,'(file.out)') fout` The error is always the same one, which makes me think I'm just missing something with the syntax of how to specify an output file.

Comment: I also tried including `status=new` as part of the read command, but it didn't work.

Comment: If you wanted to directly specify the value of the ``fout`` variable (which I'll assume is of character type) in code then the sort of  statement that you can use might simply be ``fout = 'file.out'``.  This, and the syntax and meaning of the ``read`` statement, is basic Fortran, not appropriate for teaching here.  This probably (?) isn't what you want - the file name would be the same for each run.  So think about how you want to specify things (independent of any code that might be written) and then spend some time to learn the language basics that may allow you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. Do you have any suggestions on where to find a good basics starting point? I am a Fortran novice, and have been referencing (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v111v131/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlf131.aix.doc/language_ref/associatestmt.html)

Comment: Exc introduction to Fortran 95: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to pass a number of output filenames/other variables to your program at runtime. This could be handled by using a simple [namelist](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v101v121/topic/com.ibm.xlf121.aix.doc/language_ref/namelistio.html) input file, and passing this single file to the program. The code would look like, for example:

```
character(20) :: file1, file2, file3
integer :: idum
namelist /input/ file1, file2, file3, idum

read(unit = iunit, nml = input)
```

where `iunit` is the I/O unit connected to the previously opened input file. The contents of this file would be like

```
&input                    ! Name of corresponding namelist group
  file1 = 'file1.out',
  file2 = 'file2.out',
  file3 = 'file3.out',
  idum = 1
/
```

Namelist files are very easy to handle. They don't care about the order of entries, record length or comments. You can omit any variables in the namelist file (their value will not be modified), or include multiple namelists (even of the same name) in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the simplest possible solution for you, *assuming* you have only a
few simple read(*,*)'s you can leave the code alone and simply pipe
the required strings to standard input

```
echo "file1\nfile2\n3" | executable
```

(tested under csh.. you might need to tweak a bit for a different shell)

The error message BTW makes me think you were already reading from a stdin pipe
rather than a terminal and some prior read exhausted the input.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error comes from the fact that fout cannot be read without a character string as the format specifier. Try this on line 25 (and in other read's)

`read(*,'(a)') fout`

You could improve on that if you copy the length from the definition of fout, like so (guessing the size)

`CHARACTER fout(25)
.
.
.
read(*,'(a25)') fout`

You are reading from the standard input (this is the asterisk in the first argument). I assume your input file is ASCII text. Like you have it now, you could specify the names of the output files on the first two lines of the file, then a third line for idum, then the rest of the input (if you have any).

Say your executable is **my_program.exe** and your input file (with the three lines mentioned above) is **my_input_file.txt**, you could redirect the input file to standard input like this

`%> my_program.exe < my_input_file.txt`